# Stop/Restart an animation loop on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, window-resize

I have an animation where three images rotate up and down.  JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rLgkyzgc/1/

```
$(window).load(function() {

    // Load images in BG that have been hidden by CSS
    $('.banners').show();

    // Create an empty array
    var banners = [];

    // Fill array with banner ids
    $('.banners').each(function () {
        var banner = $(this).attr('id');
        banners.push(banner);
    });

    function switchBanners(){

        var $firstBanner = $('#' + banners[0]);
        var $secondBanner = $('#' + banners[1]);
        var firstBannerHeight = $firstBanner.height();
        var secondBannerHeight = $secondBanner.height();

        $firstBanner.animate({ bottom: -firstBannerHeight }, 1200);
        $secondBanner.animate({ bottom: 0 }, 1200, function(){
            b = banners.shift(); banners.push(b);
            setTimeout(function(){
                switchBanners();
            }, 4000);
        });
    };

    // Delay initial banner switch
    setTimeout(function(){
        switchBanners();
    }, 4000);

});
```

This is great for the desktop view, but on mobile, I want to stop the animation and just show one static image.

So my questions. How can I :

- Only start the animation on page load if the window width is > 940px
- Stop (reset) the animation if the page is resized to be < 940px wide
- THEN restart the animation if the page resized to be > 940px wide

Comment: why do you want to specifically do this on resize events? Wouldn't detection of the screen on page load suffice for your needs? I'd just use `$(window).width()` and just turn a boolean true/false and that starts/skips the animation function -

Answer (score 2):

You should use `window.matchMedia` (see the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia)) to detect the viewport size on `document.ready` and when the window is resized, so something like this:

```
function resetAnimation() {
    $firstBanner.stop(true, true);
    $secondBanner.stop(true, true);
    if(window.matchMedia("(min-width: 940px)").matches) {
        //Start the animations here
    }
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    resetAnimation();
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    resetAnimation();
}
```

Note that you don't really need to `stop`the animations on document.ready, but this way you have a single function to reset the animations and then restart them only if necessary, which is something you typically want to do every time you resize the browser window, regardless of the viewport size.

Comment: This isn't working for me - largely because `$firstBanner` and `$secondBanner` are rotated as part of the animation function.

Comment: if you need to completely reset their state, you could try with `$firstBanner.removeAttr('style')`

Comment: alternatively, jQuery's `stop` function takes arguments that allow you to reset the animation state: see the documentation at http://api.jquery.com/stop/
I edited my answer to reflect the usage of `stop` that should fit your needs.

Comment: Nope, still no luck.  I've set up a fiddle - here http://jsfiddle.net/rLgkyzgc/1/ which might explain the problem better.

Answer (score 1):

I'll reference these in order:

**1. Only start the animation on page load if the window width is > 940px**

In your window load function, grab your browser width with $(window).width(). Then check that against your 940 (leave off the "px"), and perform necessary actions.

So:

```
if ($(window).width() > 940){ *actions* }
```

**2. Stop (reset) the animation if the page is resized to be < 940px wide**

To do this, you'll need to use the window resize function ($(window).resize()) and check your 940 against the browser width.

So:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  if ($(window).width() <= 940){
    *stop (reset) animation*
  }
});
```

**3. THEN restart the animation if the page resized to be > 940px wide**

This logic is essentially the same as #2, just reversed:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  if ($(window).width() > 940){
    *restart animation*
  }
});
```

Comment: I should have been clearer in my question - I know how to do what you have described - it is the **stop (reset) animation** and **restart animation** aspects of your answer that I need information on.

Comment: Ah, okay. My mistake. I'm guessing that these banners are sitting position: absolute inside a wrapper with overflow: hidden, and your function is just causing them to change their bottom values?

Comment: If that's the case, presenting an argument that causes your first banner to receive a bottom value of 0 when you travel below 940px may work.